# How to fix rerendering after select option from react multiple-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multiple-select

I can't solve why my input is rerendered  when I dynamically add next input. In first step I click on select employe from multiple select and input is dynamically created with id and name of employee.Now I can add allocation for employee but when I add next employee. Allocation value of first employee is removed.

1.Step [image: select employee for project]

2.Step [image: input is created and you can add value of allocation]

3.Step [image: select next employee for project]

4.Step [image: allocation Value of previous employee was cleared]

Component ProjectForm (I deleted some unnecessary parts of this code for this question )

```
export default class ProjectForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { project, timurProjects } = this.props;

    this.state = {
      employees:
        project && project.currentEmployees ? project.currentEmployees : [],

      technologies:
        project && project.technologies
          ? project.technologies.map(mapToId)
          : [],
      allTimurProjects: timurProjects,
      allocationValue:
        project && project.currentEmployees ? project.currentEmployees : [],
      projectTimur: null,
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdateEmployees = this.handleUpdateEmployees.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdateTechnologies = this.handleUpdateTechnologies.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { project } = this.props;
    const { allTimurProjects } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      projectTimur: allTimurProjects.find(projectTimur => {
        return project ? projectTimur.code === project.code : false;
      }),
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = values => {
    const { submitProjectForm, project, successText } = this.props;
    const { employees, technologies, projectTimur } = this.state;

    const value = {
      ...values,
      code: projectTimur ? projectTimur.code : null,
      projectManagerId: projectTimur
        ? projectTimur.projectManager.id
        : values.projectManager,
    };

    return submitProjectForm(
      value,
      employees,
      technologies,
      (project && project.id) || null,
    )
      .then(res => {
        displayNotification(successText, 'success');
        const { id } = res.data.project;

        browserHistory.push(`/projects/detail/${id}`);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw new SubmissionError(error.response.data.error);
      });
  };

  handleUpdateEmployees(employees) {
    this.setState({
      employees,
    });
  }

  handleUpdateTechnologies(technologies) {
    this.setState({
      technologies,
    });
  }

  handleUpdateAllocation = allocValue => {
    console.log(allocValue, 'ALLOCAVALUE');

    this.setState({
      allocationValue: allocValue,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      projectData,
      project,
      handleSubmit,
      error,
      pristine,
      submitting,
      title,
      submitText,
    } = this.props;

    const {
      employees,
      technologies,
      projectTimur,
      allTimurProjects,
      allocationValue,
    } = this.state;

    const employeesPristine = isEqual(
      employees,
      project && project.currentEmployees ? project.currentEmployees : [],
    );
    const technologiesPristine = isEqual(
      technologies,
      project && project.technologies ? project.technologies.map(mapToId) : [],
    );
    const allocationValuePristine = isEqual(
      allocationValue,
      project && project.currentEmployees ? project.currentEmployees : [],
    );
    const formPristine =
      employeesPristine &&
      technologiesPristine &&
      pristine &&
      allocationValuePristine;

    const defaultPMValue = projectTimur
      ? projectTimur.projectManager.name
      : '--';
    const owners =
      projectTimur && projectTimur.owner.name ? [projectTimur.owner] : [];
    const projectManagers = projectTimur
      ? [projectTimur.projectManager]
      : projectData.projectManagers;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card className="card-project-add hs-box-shadow mx-auto">
              <CardHeader>
                {project ? (
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <FontAwesome icon={['fab', 'product-hunt']} /> {title}
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="text-right">
                      <Link to={`/projects/detail/${project.id}`}>
                        Show project detail
                      </Link>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                ) : (
                  <span>
                    <FontAwesome icon={['fab', 'product-hunt']} /> {title}
                  </span>
                )}
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                {error && <Alert color="danger">{error}</Alert>}
                <Form
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}
                  onKeyPress={blockSubmitOnEnter}
                >
                  <FormRow>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs="12" lg="5">
                      <Employees
                        title="Project employees"
                        employees={projectData.employees}
                        defaultValue={
                          (project && project.currentEmployees) || []
                        }
                        onUpdate={this.handleUpdateEmployees}
                      />
                      <EmployeeAllocationTable
                        title="Project skills/technologies"
                        employees={employees}
                        project={project}
                        onUpdateAllocation={this.handleUpdateAllocation}
                        defaultValue={
                          (project && project.currentEmployees) || []
                        }
                      />

                    </Col>
                  </FormRow>
                  <FormRow>
                    <Col xs="12" md="4" lg="3">
                      <Button
                        block
                        color="success"
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={formPristine || submitting}
                      >
                        {submitText}
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col className="text-md-right mt-3 mt-md-2">
                      <RequiredFieldsNote />
                    </Col>
                  </FormRow>
                </Form>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Component Employee

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';

import { getFilteredEmployees } from '../../../util/employees';

class Employees extends Component {
  handleChange(selectedOptions) {
    const { onUpdate } = this.props;
    onUpdate &&
      onUpdate(
        selectedOptions.map(option => ({
          id: option.value,
          label: option.label,
        })),
        console.log(selectedOptions, 'SEL'),
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { title, employees } = this.props;
    let { defaultValue } = this.props;

    defaultValue = defaultValue.map(employee => ({
      value: employee.id,
      label: employee.fullNameInverted || '[unknown name]',
      allocationValue: employee.allocationValue,
    }));
    console.log(defaultValue, 'DV');

    const filteredEmployees = getFilteredEmployees(employees);

    const options = filteredEmployees.map(employee => ({
      value: employee.id,
      label: employee.fullNameInverted,
      allocationValue: employee.allocationValue,
    }));

    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <label>{title}</label>
        <Select
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          isMulti
          options={options}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    );
  }
}

Employees.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.any,
  employees: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  defaultValue: PropTypes.array,
  onUpdate: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Employees;
```

Component.EmployeeAllocationTable

```
import { Table, Input } from 'reactstrap';

export default class EmployeeAllocationTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { defaultValue } = this.props;

    defaultValue = defaultValue.map(employee => ({
      value: employee.id,
      label: employee.fullNameInverted || '[unknown name]',
      allocationValue: employee.allocationValue,
    }));

    this.state = {
      value: defaultValue,
      key: defaultValue,
      allocationValue: '',
    };
    console.log('State', this.state);
  }

  handleChangeInput = e => {
    const { employees } = this.props;
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(name, 'Name', value, 'Value');
    const employeesList =
      employees &&
      employees.find(
        employeeLabel => employeeLabel.id.toString() === e.target.name,
      );
    employeesList.allocationValue = e.target.value;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onUpdateAllocation(employeesList.allocationValue);

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { employees } = this.props;

    const newEmployeesTable =
      employees &&
      employees.map(employee => {
        const employeesList =
          employees &&
          employees.find(employeeLabel => employeeLabel.id === employee.id);

        return (
          <tr key={employee.id}>
            <td>{employeesList.fullName || employeesList.label}</td>
            <td>{employeesList.allocationValue} %</td>

            <td>
              <Input
                name={employee.id.toString()}
                value={employee.allocationValue}
                onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
                placeholder="Allocation on the project (%) "
                maxLength="3"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });

    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Allocation on the project</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{newEmployeesTable}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
const employeesList =
      employees &&
      employees.find(employeeLabel => employeeLabel.id === employee.id);
```

upd: if you dont want to rerender table you should not call onUpdate prop (handleUpdateEmployees) from on Select change
also you can do something with object

```
onUpdate(
    selectedOptions.map(option => ({
      id: option.value,
      label: option.label,
      //add here allocation and input value
    })),
```

Comment: ok. your Employees component call onUpdate prop and pass this
selectedOptions.map(option => ({
          id: option.value,
          label: option.label,
        })),
You have only object with id and label
then you render array with this object to table
Object dont contain input data and %

Comment: I tried this ... handleChange(selectedOptions) {
    const { onUpdate } = this.props;
    onUpdate &&
      onUpdate(
        selectedOptions.map(option => ({
          id: option.value,
          label: option.label, allocationValue:option.allocationValue
        })),
        console.log(selectedOptions, 'SEL'),
      );
  }

Comment: How do you pass selected options to 

handleChange(selectedOptions) {
    const { onUpdate } = this.props;
    onUpdate &&
      onUpdate(
        selectedOptions.map(option => ({
          id: option.value,
          label: option.label,
        })),
        console.log(selectedOptions, 'SEL'),
      );
  }

onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}